# After installing Rstudio and launching it, I get an rsession.exe system error saying "Rlapack.dll is missing from your computer"

Tags: r, rstudio

I've just installed R x64 4.0.0 to my computer and have been trying to install RStudio.

When launching R by itself, I'm able to install packages and execute code no problem. However, when I open RStudio I get a system error saying that Rlapack.dll is missing from my computer and am prompted to reinstall the program which I have done several times to no avail. I have also tried reinstalling RStudio several times.

The following errors appear on the RStudio console after "oking" the system error popup:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I have also searched for the supposed missing dll in the R installation and found it in this location "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\x64"

I am unable to run scripts through the RStudio IDE - does anyone know how to fix this dll issue and get RStudio working?

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the internet and spending the best part of a day trying to get to the bottom of this, I have found something that seems to work..

Copy `Rlapack.dll` from

`C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\x64`

and paste it into the following locations:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\library\stats\libs\x64
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\library\Matrix\libs\x64
```